# Javascript detect browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

Is it possible to detect if the browser is closing in JavaScript? I tried using:

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    //Code
});
```

and:

```
window.onbeforeunload = ExecuteMyCode;
function ExecuteMyCode() {
    //Code
}
```

But this both executes when we also click a link, button,... I ONLY  want to detect the browser close event.

Comment: button? What button? A browser button? I think you can only detect when a user moves away from your current page / website. Not when the browser is actually closed. Why would you want that anyway?

Comment: I need it to remove my cookies before closing (and setting a time for the cookie isn't an option)

Comment: If you just set the cookies as session cookies then these will automatically be removed by the browser when it closes anyway - what you are describing is default behaviour.

Comment: What you could do is check with the `beforeunload` if someone is moving away from your website (so to new website or close the tab / browser). Than you can remove your cookie.

Comment: @putvande how do you do that? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to determine where the user is going. Only that they're leaving...

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code it will ensure your mouse position is on the close button then and then it will execute further.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {

            if (event.clientY < 0) {
                // DO YOUR STUFF BEFORE CLOSING..
            }
                return "Message to display user before close.";
            }
}
```

Comment: clientY  is undefined in chrome browser